# make the query dynamically to change using sanity.io groq

Tags: javascript, sanity

Hi there I'm trying to make a post request where I want to update one field on sanity.io

this is my query

```
patch: {
          id: "f6c46b53-9313-4354-a4d6-7a40b06ee4c0",
          set: {
            `rewardItem[_key == \"${key}\"].lastTimeReward`: "TEst",
          },
        }
```

but this won't let me even run my project,
its giving me this error on console.log: Unexpected token;

When I do my query like this, it works

```
patch: {
          id: "f6c46b53-9313-4354-a4d6-7a40b06ee4c0",
          set: {
            "rewardItem[_key == \"e88959e43ce7\"].lastTimeReward": "Test",
          },
        }
      }]
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `set`-property is an object, and you can't enter a dynamic key directly into the object. To do what you are trying to do here, you can [wrap the dynamic key in square brackets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) like this. That should give you the output you desire

```js
const variable = "example"
const a = { [`template ${variable}`]: "value" }
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, this one worked, I have been trying this for 2-3 hours. Thanks a lot again

Comment: Feel free to upvote the answer, and mark as a solution :) Keep up the good work, I was stuck on this once too!

Comment: I'll do that after 5 mins because stackoverflow isn't letting me do it now. After 5 mins of course.